# How to change Header Logo in Laravel Mailable template?

Tags: laravel, email

I want to change the `logo` from the `header`of the `markdown template` of `mailables` in Laravel.

original **`views/vendor/mail/html/header.blade.php`**:

```
<tr>
<td class="header">
<a href="{{ $url }}" style="display: inline-block;">
@if (trim($slot) === 'Laravel')
<img src="https://laravel.com/img/notification-logo.png" class="logo" alt="Laravel Logo">
@else
{{ $slot }}
@endif
</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

and I want to change the `img src` to:

```
<img src={{ $content }} class="logo" alt="Logo">
```

variable `$content` coming from mailable **`ContactMail.php`**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use phpDocumentor\Reflection\DocBlock\Tags\Var_;

class ContactMail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->content = "storage/hg5zkMDJTAWaIjc8hH5jqtb5FGmOXfpccha2k0A4.png";

        return $this->markdown('emails.contact');
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return view('vendor.mail.html.header')->with('content', $this->content);
    }
}
```

but it ends up throwing:

```
ErrorException
Undefined variable $content (View: C:\Users\Artur\PhpstormProjects\stuttard.de\resources\views\vendor\mail\html\header.blade.php)

$content is undefined
```

How do I pass `$content` to `header.blade.php` correctly?

**Edit:**

**`ContactController.php`**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Mail\ContactMail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;


class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
        return new ContactMail();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you finally fix it?

Comment: @jssDev Yes, I was able to do it but unfortunately can't find the right file anymore, that I had to edit. It is possible.

Comment: What a pity, knowledge lost.

Comment: @jssDev I've found it. I'm creating a customizable laravel mail template with `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail`. This creates a new set of files in `resources/views/vendor/mail/html` with customizable `blade components` which the mail is built from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that after running:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

a new set of customizable `blade files` is created in:

```
/resources/views/vendor/mail/html
```

These are building blocks for the mailable template and can be edited.

Answer (score 1):

First, put the logo file in the `public/img` folder.

Next, update files:

1. `resources/views/vendor/mail/html/header.blade.php`

```html
<tr>
    <td class="header">
        <a href="{{ $url }}" style="display: inline-block;">
            <img src="{{ url('img/your-logo.png') }}" class="logo" alt="Logo">
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

2. `resources/views/vendor/mail/html/themes/default.css`

Find `.logo` and adjust the properties to your needs. If your image is **500x100px**, then I recommend setting `width` to **250px** and `[max-]height` to **50px** due to the retina displays.

```css
.logo {
    height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

3. `resources/views/vendor/mail/html/message.blade.php`

Replace the header slot code with this one:

```
{{-- Header --}}
@slot('header')
    @include('mail::header', ['url' => config('app.url')])
@endslot
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You pass variable data not content
Change your code to

```
<img src={{ $data }} class="logo" alt="Logo">
```

Added more answer
Try this you need to define $content variable first

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use phpDocumentor\Reflection\DocBlock\Tags\Var_;

class ContactMail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $content;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->content = "storage/hg5zkMDJTAWaIjc8hH5jqtb5FGmOXfpccha2k0A4.png";

        return $this->markdown('emails.contact');
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return view('vendor.mail.html.header')->with('content', $this->content);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was an artifact. I corrected it from the question. The same error occurs.

Comment: Is the error still the same?ErrorException
Undefined variable $content (View: C:\Users\Artur\PhpstormProjects\stuttard.de\resources\views\vendor\mail\html\header.blade.php)

$content is undefined

Comment: @Ry yes, exactly the same